# How do I use Ruby gem selenium-webdriver with Chromium?

Tags: ruby, linux, selenium, debian, chromium

I'm on Debian 8.2 "Jessie" with Ruby 2.1.5.

In `test.rb`, I have `require selenium-webdriver`, but when I run `Selenium::WebDriver.for :ChromeDriver` I get this error:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:72:in `for': unknown driver: :ChromeDriver (ArgumentError)
```

I don't have Chrome, but do have Cromium. How do I get Selenium to cooperate?

Comment: There isn't a specific driver for Chromium on *nix systems. So you need to use :chrome as the driver, in place of :ChromeDriver. Try Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome.

Comment: I got this error: `/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:37:in executable_path': Unable to find the chromedriver executable. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)`. I went to 'http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html' and put `chromedriver` from v2.20 in `/usr/local/bin`. Still got the same error.

Comment: Ok, thats at least gives more details. Try using this gem to setup your chromedriver : https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper

Comment: @Sam That worked! You can post your solution as an answer if you want me to mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a specific driver for Chromium on *nix systems. So you need to use `:chrome` as the driver, in place of `:ChromeDriver`, e.g.,  `Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome`

Also, use this gem for a hassel free setup of chromedriver on your execution system: https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper